# How to Delete Partition in terminal

Tags: macos, partition, apfs

[image] i just want my mac to have one partition so i can use all the full 250GB. Disk utility did not work. Below is partitions and identifiers if anyone could help me with the CMD i need to return everything back to one i would really appreciate it.

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨STORAGE⁩                 195.0 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 293.0 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                613.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨MAC⁩                     24.0 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 24.0 GB    disk1s5s1
```

Comment: That's basically what you have. The only other partition is the EFI partition (209.7 MB), but that's both tiny and (at least in some situations) *required*.

Comment: Why do you think that any of that needs deleting? It looks like a bog standard partitioning scheme set up at the factory. All partitions there are *required.*

Comment: @BoboJenkinz The only thing not standard is the size of the volume 5 (and 6 of course). The standard size of the system volume is about 12 or 15 go. I think you have an system update not finished or completed.

Answer (score 3):

That is a perfectly standard setup. You have one APFS partition containing [some volumes, created by the system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305110/37797), sharing the space. There’s nothing to be deleted. You can already use the full 250 GB minus what is taken by the operating system.